Ground plane for SMPS EMI-Filter?
I am designing a board including various switch mode power supplies, e.g. Buck, boost, and so on. The application notes recommend using split ground planes for power and analog parts, however after some research (e.g. Rick Hartley's video about grounding) I decided to just use a single ground plane and try to seperate the power components and analog components as much as possible.
One remaining question I have is about the usage of ground planes when designing an EMI filter. I've read somewhere that you should cut out the ground plane beneath the EMI filter and all inductors to reduce noise coupling.
Is this necessary?

Using a single ground plane for the entire board is a common practice. Here is an article on the effect of the gap between the microstrip line and the top ground plane2 https://www.pcbway.com/blog/2/The_effect_of_the_gap_between_the_microstrip_line_and_the_top_ground_plane2.html  Cutting out the ground plane beneath inductors and EMI filters can help reduce noise coupling and improve EMI performance. However, you should consider the overall layout, thermal management, and structural integrity of the PCB.

A ground plane is a reference plane.
Anywhere the reference changes, a new ground plane is appropriate, as well as decoupling or isolation between any planes that should share connections.
Here is an example, where a cable connection is expanded into a local ground plane for shielding purposes, and common mode chokes (CMCs) are used to decouple the shield (and the signals on it) from circuit ground, without requiring galvanic isolation: 
What is the best practice when replacing a ribbon-cable ferrite clamp with chip ferrite beads? 
This was seen as a better solution than filtering individual lines, or directly tying the cable to the board in an unknown EMI environment (which might've made emissions or susceptibility worse as a result).  (Though all three options were also provided, just in case.)  Compared to a ribbon-cable ferrite bead, the solution may be of dubious value (i.e. parts cost), but it is at least easier and more reliable on mechanical assembly (the board is machine assembled and already made).
A mains filter typically contains one or more CMCs, so the nodes between them can be considered local reference by the same token.  It's rare that any more than filtering or protection devices would be placed here, but you could indeed pour these areas locally, assuming no other limitations.
You certainly wouldn't extend the main circuit's ground plane under the CMC(s) / mains input, because that's precisely the reference plane you're trying to avoid.  That is: a scenario where the main circuit has some unavoidable AC voltage with respect to ground (driven across an isolation transformer, heatsink insulation, proximity to chassis, etc.), and that's why you are using CMCs towards the mains.
Line filters are often laid out in a single-layer style, because it really doesn't matter: more distance between lines just adds (if very slightly) to CMC leakage inductance (used for DM filtering), and the stray inductance of the X1/X2 capacitors isn't reduced significantly by overlapping their nets (to make a parallel-plane geometry).  A non-approved PCB might also not be rated for full category surge voltage within or across layers, effectively forcing a 2+ layer board to a single one anyway.  And, single-layer boards are still very common in commodity PSUs -- when they're making a million of something, even the PCB cost matters!
The result is, a typical mains filter has good filtering down to 100kHz or so, and up to some 10s of MHz.  Frequencies higher than this, are difficult to deal with, because parasitics of the components used, matter, and layout also needs to be tighter.
With optimal component choice (e.g. a geometric series of CMCs of different sizes), a ground plane design, and shields too for that matter, we could craft a line filter with very high attenuation over a very wide frequency range (100s MHz).  Thing is, it's just not worth it: SMPS don't usually create much noise above 100MHz, and managing those frequencies isn't very meaningful from the mains direction -- it's as likely radiated from the active circuit itself, heatsinks, output side, etc.
There are high-frequency issues in cutting-edge technologies (GaN converters with low ~ns switching edges), but they also benefit from a raised cutoff (~MHz switching frequencies), and being smaller in general, shields are more affordable.  They're also a premium product right now, so a few other cost-adders aren't a big problem; they don't have to be highly optimized.

IMO separating ground planes is a way to control return currents. Another way to this is with proper placement of voltage regulators and components. Return currents from loads will follow the ground plane back to where the power comes in (connector). If this is an alternating current with noise it will cause the ground to bounce. If you can move analog components away from the return currents then you'll have less noise.
This doesn't work if the whole ground plane is acting like a dipole, so you may need to separate them.
